# how to get sum base on the return value

Tags: crystal-reports

Are there anyway I can get sum of 1234 to work as below?

```
-----------------
      1234  1  a     10.00
      1234  1  b      1.00
      1234  1  c   1200.00
     --------------
      1234  2  a      1.00
      1234  2  b      1.00
      1234  2  c      1.00
      --------------
     Sum of 1234
               a     11.00
               b      2.00
               c   1201.00
-------------------
Total              1214.00
```

I have try to group by abc but it didn't present the way I expected

Comment: You need another grouping by the first column "around" the first group.

Comment: Thankyou but I figured out another way using the edit running total and evaluate with a formula.